# Check href for hyperlink using Selenium webdriver with Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I want to check an url for hyperlink is correct without clicking on hyperlink.

Suppose, I've following html code -

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

I want to check that intended webpage for 'Google' hyperlink is http://www.google.com without clicking on it. How can it be done with Selenium webdriver with Ruby

Comment: Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4137659/326543) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the attribute value of an element using the [`Element#attribute`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#attribute-instance_method) method:

```
link = driver.find_element(:css, 'a')
link.attribute("href")
#=> "http://www.google.com"
```